# Got Unresolved reference: setText when convert java to kotlin

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I want to use Android Studio to convert a android app demo from `java` to `kotlin`. But I got some Errors.

some of the Java code are:

```
   public static class FileServerAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {
    private boolean isname=true;
    private String name="啦啦啦";
    private Context context;
    private TextView statusText;
    Handler myhandler=new Handler(){
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            switch (msg.what){
                case 10:
                    statusText.setText("XXXXX");
            }
        }
    };

    /**
     * @param context
     * @param statusText
     */
    public FileServerAsyncTask(Context context, View statusText) {
        this.context = context;
        this.statusText = (TextView) statusText;
    }
```

The Studio convert them to

```
 class FileServerAsyncTask
    /**
     * @param context
     * *
     * @param statusText
     */
    (private val context: Context, statusText: View) : AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>() {
        private val isname = true
        private var name = "啦啦啦"
        private var statusText: TextView

        init {
            this.statusText = statusText as TextView
        }

        internal var myhandler = object : Handler() {
            override fun handleMessage(msg: Message) {
                when (msg.what) {
                    10 -> statusText.setText("XXXXX")
                    else -> {

                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

But there are errors at `10 -> statusText.setText("XXXXX")`

I change it to `10 -> statusText.text = "XXXX"`, but the error still exist. However other sentences like this in the same file are ok.

What's wrong?

Comment: I think you should complete your else block. This is because of the way Kotlin handles null and since statusText can't be null, it is giving you an error because it doesn't know what will be in the else block yet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
(private val context: Context, statusText: TextView) : AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>() {
    private val isname = true
    private val name = "啦啦啦"
    private val statusText: TextView
    internal var myhandler: Handler = object : Handler() {
        override fun handleMessage(msg: Message) {
            when (msg.what) {
                10 -> statusText.text = "XXXXXX"
            }
        }
    }

    init {
        this.statusText = statusText as TextView
    }

    override fun doInBackground(vararg params: Void): String? {
        return null
    }
}
```

The problem was in the constructor change view to textview.